# Js. Click event added programmatically, but fires only once, when code is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click, jquery-events

I’m creating n buttons dynamically with JS/jQuery and I’m dynamically adding a button click event.

The problem is that when the function AddImageInTagTest() is called it creates all the buttons and fires the click event, without me clicking any button.

The other issue is that when I click one of the buttons created dynamically the click event  function doesn’t fire.

How come?

```
var count = 0;
function AddImageInTagTest(tagId, imageSrcPathAndimageFileName) {
    var fileNameWithExtension;

    fileNameWithExtension = imageSrcPathAndimageFileName.split("\\").pop(); //get just the filename with ext from the path
    $(tagId).html($(tagId).html() + "<img alt='' src='" +"\\" +imageSrcPathAndimageFileName +"'/>"+"<input id='Button"+count.toString()+"' type='button' value='delete image' />");
    $("#Button" + count.toString()).click(delete_image_custom());
    count++;
}

function delete_image_custom() {
    alert("Button is clicked");
}
```

I've changed and added and anonymous function in the click event, but nothing happends when I click.

```
$("#Button" + count.toString()).click(function () { console.log("click event fired")});
```

I've modified the function call to:

```
$("#Button" + count.toString()).onClick(delete_image_custom); but nothing
```

Comment: `.click` expects a function, not whatever the function returns; `undefined` in this case

Comment: I've change the event function to $("#Button" + count.toString()).click(function () { console.log("click event fired")}); but still no result.

Comment: `$("#Button" + count.toString()).click(delete_image_custom());`  <-- The `()` is wrong

Comment: Recommendations:  1) Add a single click event to the parent element so that you don't have to worry about the buttons added dynamically.  2) Use the newer `on` method instead of `click`.  Without seeing other code, it's hard to make a full suggestion.

Comment: @epascarello ok, why? I just need the function pointer. Function reference with no parenthesis.

Comment: Because you are calling the function, not assigning a reference to the function.

Comment: With a single event on the parent element, you can add as many buttons as you want and not have to add a click event as you add each element.  The parent element handles it.

Comment: In other words doing `delete_image_custom()` executes the function and gets a return value that is then being sent to `click`.  Doing `delete_image_custom` says go execute this function when the element is clicked.

Comment: @all I've modified the function call to $("#Button" + count.toString()).onClick(delete_image_custom); but nothing

Comment: There is no onClick in jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click event fires because you are calling the function instead of assiging the reference.

```
$("#Button" + count.toString()).click(delete_image_custom());
                                                         ^^
```

The () is calling the method. You would do that if the method you called would return a function to execute. In your case you want to assign a reference, so drop the `()`.

```
$("#Button" + count.toString()).click(delete_image_custom);
```

And you should not be replacing all of the html when you add new content. Use append() to add the new elements to the end. When you replace the html and rewrite it, you will be destroying elements and their event handlers. Appending will not do that.

```
$(tagId).append("<img alt='' src='" +"\\" +imageSrcPathAndimageFileName +"'/>"+"<input id='Button"+count.toString()+"' type='button' value='delete image' />");
```

---

If all that said, why not just use event delegation?

```
$("#CommonParentElement").on("click", ".commonClassOnButton", function(){    
    var button = $(this);
    console.log(button);
});
```

This will eliminate the need to add new events when you add new elements.

Comment: Not using append was generating my issue.